# Rigorous construction of the pointwise limit of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems, measurable-functions, pointwise-convergence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let 
$$X_1,X_2,X_3,... \: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
be a sequence of random variables. Moreover, let there be an event $A \subseteq \Omega$ with $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ such that, for all $\omega \in A$, it holds that
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n(w) $$
exists and is finite.

From all of this, how can I **rigorously** construct a random variable 
$$ X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
for which it holds that
$$ X_n \rightarrow X $$
almost surely, **without** setting 
$$ X := X_n \mathbb{1}_{A} \quad? $$
Note that, since $X$ is a random variable, it of course needs to be $\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable. Furthermore, note that the range of $X$ should stay finite and should exclude the possibility, that $\lvert X(\omega) \rvert  = \infty $ for some $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: Set $X' = \liminf_{n\to\infty} X_n$, which always exists in $[-\infty, \infty]$, and $X = X'\mathbf{1}_{\{X'\in\mathbb{R}\}}$. This $X$ always exists for any sequence of random variables and $X'(\omega) = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega)$ whenever the limit exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X(\omega)=\lim\sup X_n(\omega)$ if $\lim\sup X_n(\omega) \in \mathbb R$ and $X(\omega)=0$ otherwise. This $X$ has the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you. How can one prove that the function you suggest is measurable ?

Comment: That is very standard. $\lim \sup$ of a sequence of measurable functions is always measurable so the set of points where $\lim \sup$ is finite is also in the sigma algebra. That makes $X$ measurable.

Comment: Thanks, Would it also work if I defined a function
$$ h :[- \infty, \infty] \rightarrow (- \infty, \infty) $$
with $h(x) = x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h(x) = 0$ otherwise, and then set
$$ X(\omega) := h(\limsup X_n(\omega)) \ ?$$

Comment: Yes, that works.